# Selecting one post to display in a liquid loop

Tags: loops, jekyll, liquid

I'm building a jekyll site. I have a loop setup - 
`{% for article in site.posts limit:5 %} 
     {% if article.tag == "infographic" %}
         <a class="infographic tag" href="/tags/infographics.html">{{ article.tag }}</a>
     {% endif %}
 {% endfor %}`

This loop spits out the latest 5 posts in my infographic tag. I would like the loop to produce **only the third latest post**. Any ideas on making this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is really difficult for tags. If you use `infographic` as a category, it could be really simple:

```
for article in site.categories.infographic | offset: 2 | limit: 1
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked for my tags as well. Another option would be - {{ forloop.index == 3 }}: https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/objects/for-loops - I like yours better.

Comment: edit - after further testing, you were right, it is important to use categories